# Parent/Child MySQL query with CASE/WHEN or switch

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement

I’m using PHP to dynamically add another table to a page based on a parent/child relationship.

I’ve greatly simplified things so lets suppose I have a table 'FAMILY' with three columns Parent  Int(6), Child varchar(15), and Fname varchar(25). The table has four rows, whose values are;
    Row 1 :  4, NULL , Bill
    Row 2:   5, 4, Tom
    Row 3:   6, NULL, Frank
    Row 4:   7, 4, Sam

As you can tell Tom and Frank are children of Bill. And so Bill is the parent of Tom and Sam.

Regardless of whose record I’m currently looking at, I would like to be able to dynamically see the other associated records as well. Forget the PHP part, I have that working. I just need the MySQL query.

The way I see it, I need one query that will do two different things depending on the value of child. 
1: If Child is NULL (or blank) as in Row 1, I need it to return Row 2 and 4 based on the parent value of 4.  In other words I’m looking at a Parent.
2) If Child is NOT NULL, as in Rows 2 & 4, I need it to return row 1 and the other row 2 or 4 depending which child I was looking at.  Now I’m looking at a child record.

```
SELECT * FROM FAMILY WHERE
 CASE WHEN Child  IS NOT NULL then parent = 4
 WHEN child IS NULL then child = 4
 END
 GROUP BY PARENT
```

I’m pretty sure that I’m using CASE/WHEN incorrectly but after trying about a thousand things I give up and need to ask for help.

Please a MySQL query that can evaluate if it’s a parent or child and then pull the appropriate row(s) would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is a risk of putting the same connection in two different rows redundantly. This might speedup some things, but I would try to avoid that. If Tom is child of Bill, Bill is parent of Tom.  Then I would try to break it up into two queries: one gets the list of all the parents of a person, one the list of all the children. If one list is empty, it is empty and you can easily tell the user "there are no parents" or "there are no children".

Answer (score 1):

Not much sure from your question statement but you can modify your `WHERE` condition to be like below

```
 WHERE (Child  IS NOT NULL AND parent = 4)
 OR COALESCE(child, 4) = 4
```